# How do i redirect code from terminal to a drawing app?

Tags: c, unix, input, terminal, output

I am trying to create a simple program using C, that reads data from a text file and then creates a graph based on that data. I am running UNIX.

Half of my code is meant to use the terminal for printf and scanf for user input and displaying messages, and once that half is complete, the other half needs to start.

The 2nd half is meant to create a graph using drawapp.jar, a seperate drawing program.

When i compile using gcc -o filename filename.c and run using ./filename , it compiles fun but only runs the first half

When i compile using gcc -o filename filename.c graphics.c and run using ./filename | java -jar drawapp.jar , it compiles fine but when it runs it opens drawapp.jar which freezes on a blank grey screen and the terminal window does not show the first half of my code where it is meant to ask for user input and just freezes, the terminal allows me to type but it does nothing

Image on this link shows my problem: http://picpaste.com/Untitled-IlRWjqLN.png

How do i get the c code correct so that it does the first half in terminal then switches to drawapp.jar?

Thanks

Comment: pic's as clear as your question.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` and `execlp()` with `"java -jar drawapp.jar"`

Comment: +1 and a pipe to send data collected and computed in half#1 as stdin to the java process. (prolly shoulda mentioned that =P).

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/pipes.html, you're welcome, also consider the WhozCraig answer ;)

Comment: thanks, i tried using the 4.3 code and replacing the wc with drawapp but still no luck, im still getting the grey screen, the first line of my int main(void) section is a scanf where the user enters the name of the file that contains the data, that does not show up in the terminal when run and neither does any of the subsequent lines of code, a drawapp window pops up but is grey as in the picture above :(

Comment: Ok, try to run result of your app directly in this way: java -jar drawapp.jar | ./graphGen2 , (in the first pic your pipe was inverted: ./graphGen2 | java -jar drawapp.jar)

Comment: forget fork(),  "java -jar drawapp.jar data2.txt" works? then output of printf(s) must run

Comment: how do i implement a fork()?

Comment: fork() has no params, execl() returns 0 on succesfull calls: int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...); but if drawjar doesn't work directly from command line then fork is not an issue

Comment: ok, i typed in java -jar drawapp.jar in the terminal and it opens with a grey screen

Comment: "java -jar drawapp.jar yourfile.txt" doesn't work? then you must fix this before run you program

Comment: the text file does not contain the instructions for the drawing, the instructions for the drawing are in the c file graphGen2, the c file reads the text file and imports the data into arrays which then need to be plotted into graphs

Comment: So graphGen2 creates the arrays which are transfered to stdin of the drawapp.jar. So I think first you should run graphGen2 standalone (without piping) and then see what output apears. The relevant output the copy and paste into a file (maybe xxx.txt is a good choice), and then run java -jar drawapp.jar <xxx.txt, and see what happens, wether it understands that xxx.txt.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand, your program's stdout is piped to the java-process. Now you first want to communicate with the user using the terminal-window, and then send commands via stdout to the java.process.
So you could just open /dev/tty for output

```
FILE *f=fopen ("/dev/tty", "w");
fprintf (f, "Hi there\n");
```

and talk this way to the terminal. If you have output with no \n at the end, you might have to use fflush:

```
fprintf (f, "enter name: ");
fflush (f);
```